# Selecting according to a varying number of columns

Tags: pandas

I have a df with columns 'filter1','filter2',..'filter1000'.
The values of each of those columns is either the text 'true' or 'false'.

Now I want to write a function which takes as an input a list of those filter names (for example ['filter8','filter284'...,'filter323']) and return only the lines for which one or more of the corresponding filter value was 'true'.

I did write this code:

```
def filter_by_precalculated_filters(df,filters_names):
    df = pd.concat(df.loc[df[filter_name] == 'true'] for filter_name in filters_names) 
    #do something with df here etc...
```

but this solution seems bad because:
1.Slow
2.If the filters aren't one-hot,then this will create df with duplicates (to my understanding).

So what's a good solution?

Comment: `df[df[filter_name].eq('true').any(axis=1)]`

Comment: There are varying number of filters eg it can be just ['filter8'] but it can be,as the question states, ['filter9','filter17','filter89'].  Your answer deals with just one single filter which is something I already know how to do (see the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isin()`method in `pandas.DataFrame()`:

`df = df.loc[df['column name to apply filter'].isin(filter_list)]`

Comment: The question states that you have,as columns, 'filter1'...'filter1000'. Your answer is a selection on just one column,so it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Then loop through each column, place the values in a list, now you have a list of list then filter the original dataframe per iteration of your list of filters then concatenate it within the same function. You don't expect people to write the code for you now do you? We're simply giving an idea how to tackle the problem. Basically, the isin method is key here of you want to use those filters and get individial dataframes per filter.

Comment: I wrote the code that you described now in the question. I do expect people who answer to read the question. By the way,isin is not useful as I already know the one value I am looking  for ('true')

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.loc[(df[filters_names]=='true').any(axis=1)]
```

In my case. If there are several values you are interested in then:

```
df = df.loc[(df[filters_names].isin(values)).any(axis=1)]
```